# AngularJs ng-click inside datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

I have a [datatable](https://www.datatables.net/) loaded from javascript via an ajax call. This is part of my datatable:

```
"columns": [
         { "data": "carType" },
         { "data": "id" },                        
         { "data": "carChassis" },
         { "data": "initialKm" },
         { "data": "note" },
         {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
             return '<a data-ng-click="downloadFile('+row.idCar+')"> <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o fa-2x" style="color:green;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
         }
         },
         {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
             return '<a data-ng-click="downloadFile('+row.idCar+')"> <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
         }
         },
         {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
             return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteCar" data-toggle="modal"'
             +'data-target="#deleteCarModal">Delete</button>'   
         }
         }
         ],
```

but it doesn't call my `downloadFile` function:

```
//Download file
    $scope.downloadFile = function(idCar) {
        $.fileDownload("../cars/download/" + idcar , {
            successCallback: function (url) {
            },
            failCallback: function (HttpServletResponse, url) {
                notifyMessage("Error downloading file", 'error');
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    }
```

If I add `href=""` to the `a` tag it works but reloads the datatable. Have you ever had this problem?

This is the HTML page:

```
body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="hidden" id="role"
        th:value="${#authentication.getAuthorities()}">
    <div class="wrapper" data-ng-controller="carController">
        <!-- Header nd menu fragment -->
        <div th:replace="../fragments/dashboard-header :: dashboard-header"></div>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>Cars Management</h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a th:href="@{/}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a th:href="@{/fleetAndCar/}">><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Fleets
                            management
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Cars management</li>
                </ol>
            </section>
            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Cars</h3>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <!--  Fleets table -->
                                <table id="carsTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Car type</th>
                                            <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>Car chassis</th>
                                            <th>Initial Km</th>
                                            <th>Note</th>
                                            <th>Datatable</th>
                                            <th>Acquisition log</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                                <!-- Create two equals button because when I am on desktop I show the text add fleet otherwise the + and the tooltip. 
                                This is need because otherwise the text goes out the button -->
                                <button id="addCarButton" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary visible-lg col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-11"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCarModal">Add car</button>
                                <button id="addCarButton" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary hidden-lg col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCarModal">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        title="Add car"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenIdFleet" th:value="${idFleet}"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- Modal to add car -->
        <div class="modal" id="addCarModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Car parameters</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- form start -->
                        <form novalidate class="simple-form" name="newCarForm">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Fleet application</label>
                                        <!-- Show fleet application -->
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                            value="{{fleetApplication}}" readonly="readonly" /> <input
                                            type="hidden" data-ng-model="newCar.fleet">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="radio">
                                        <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
                                            ng-click="existingCar()" checked> Use existing car
                                            type
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="radio">
                                        <label> <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios"
                                            data-ng-click="newCarType()"> Create new car type
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" id=existingCarType>
                                    <label>CarType</label>
                                    <ui-select data-ng-init="updateCarType()" id="selectCarType"
                                        theme="bootstrap" style="width: 100%;"
                                        data-ng-model="newCar.carType" required> <ui-select-match
                                        placeholder="Select car type">
                                    {{$select.selected.idCarType}}</ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices
                                        repeat="carType.idCarType as carType in (carTypeList | filter: $select.search) track by carType.idCarType">
                                    <span data-ng-bind="carType.idCarType"></span> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" id=newCarType style="display: none;">
                                    <label>CarType</label> <input id="carTypeText"
                                        data-ng-model="newCar.carType" type="text"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="New car Type" disabled
                                        required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Id</label> <input data-ng-model="newCar.id"
                                        id="identifier" type="text" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Identifier" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>km</label><span id="errmsg"
                                        style="float: right; color: red"></span> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newCar.initialKm" id="initialKm" type="number"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Initial Km" min="0" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Car chassis</label> <input
                                        data-ng-model="newCar.carChassis" id="carChassis" type="text"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Car chassis" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Note </label>(optional)
                                    <textarea data-ng-model="newCar.note" class="form-control"
                                        rows="2" maxlength="100"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button data-ng-disabled="newCarForm.$invalid"
                            data-ng-click="createCar(newCar)" type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary">Create car</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->

        <!-- Modal delete car -->
        <div class="modal" id="deleteCarModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete car</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="box-body">Are you sure? The car will be deleted
                            permanently, you won't be able to recover it.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" data-ng-click="deleteCar()"
                            id="deleteCarButton">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the html on columns is not parsed by the angular engine. Post the html code.

Comment: I suggest you only post the HTML relevant to the table, if people have to hunt for the part related to your post, they may not even attempt to help.

Comment: once your table is rendered do a big $compile($yourTableElement) to compile it with Angular and have the directives work

Comment: I have tried with "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                             $compile(nRow)($scope);                            
                            },  but $compile is not defined